# Get start and end point of opening in Revit

Tags: c#, vb.net, revit-api

How can I get the start and end point coordinates of openings in Revit? I am trying to divide a wall into panels of certain width and for that if there is an opening, Door or window in between i have to panelize accordingly. As of for now I only wants to get the start and end point coordinates of openings.

I have tried following code but that isn't giving coordinates.

```
Wall wall = element as Wall;

var openings = wall.FindInserts(true, true, true, true);
foreach (var opening in openings)
{
 ElementId elementId = new ElementId(opening.IntegerValue);
 Element element = ActiveDoc.GetElement(elementId);
 LocationCurve locationCurve = element.Location as LocationCurve;
 var OpnStartPt = locationCurve.Curve.GetEndPoint(0);
 var OpnEndtPt = locationCurve.Curve.GetEndPoint(1);
}
```

Comment: i think var openings should be = wall.FindInserts(true, false, false, false);
As you are only looking for Openings

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the opening has its own geometry, retrieve that, extract all vertices, and pick the ones you need. You can use RevitLookup and other tools to explore the database element and its properties before hardcoding.